# Jquery domready issues with ajax, element.on('click', function) not solving

Tags: ajax, dom, jquery, document-ready

I have an outer framing page and an inner contents page on my site. The inner page is changed via an ajax call

At the moment I have outer page js as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //page load functions
         $('.menu').click(function(){ 
              $("#innerpage").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);    
              $('#innerpage').ajaxComplete(function() {
                             //do some stuff here
              });   
         });
 });
```

I then inner page js as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //page load functions
             $('.innermenu').click(function(){ 
                  $("#innerpageresults").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); 
                  $('#innerpageresults').ajaxComplete(function() {
                                 //do some stuff here
                  });   
             });
     });
```

This all works but ideally I would like all the javascript in one external file but I am having trouble getting to this.

I am trying to solve this by using the following code in the outer page but I must be doing something wrong cause its not firing after the inner page is changed through the ajax call:

```
$('.innermenu').on("click", function(){
                      $("#innerpageresults").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); 
                      $('#innerpageresults').ajaxComplete(function() {
                                     //do some stuff here
                      });   
}):
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)?

Comment: most of it... there is a lot and most of it seemed like waffle. I followed the examples and the most basic one was in the above format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
$('body').on("click",'.innermenu',  function(){
                      $("#innerpageresults").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); 
                      $('#innerpageresults').ajaxComplete(function() {
                                     //do some stuff here
                      });   
}):
```

in this way you are delegating to the `<body>` element the handling of the `click` event for elements that have the class innermenu.

if `.menu` wraps all the `.innermenu` elements you could write thi even better:

```
$('.menu').on("click",'.innermenu',  function(){
                      $("#innerpageresults").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); 
                      $('#innerpageresults').ajaxComplete(function() {
                                     //do some stuff here
                      });   
}):
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it is giving the same result. works before the ajax call but not after

Comment: Thank you, I have it working now, both of your examples do in fact work - in my real world example I had also declared some variables in my doc.ready function I had forgotton to declare them within the .on function.

Comment: @WebweaverD if both of them work, stick to the second one, it will be more responsive as the evnt has to bubble up the DOM only to the .menu elements and not to the body

Answer (score 2):

Try using the event delegation syntax of `.on`

```
$("#innerpage").on("click",".innermenu",function(){...});
```